# Heatmap of values in R

Tags: r, ggplot2, heatmap

I am not sure why I am not able to see the desired results.

I am trying to make heatmap of GHI using data with 8760 values (24 hours x 365 days). Data is linked [here](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1y-0aO4XiujNzIzAuMbUqB0ZpFb5eOoaX/edit?usp=drive_web&ouid=107551134942623551079&rtpof=true).

Here is my code:

```
day <- data$Day
time <- hm(data$Time)
hour <- hour(time)
year <- 2023
month <- data$month
month <- month_num <- month(as.Date(paste0("2000-", day), format="%Y-%j"))
GHI <- data$GHI

heatmap <- data.frame(GHI, year, month,day, hour)

  heatmap_GHI <-ggplot(heatmap,aes(day,hour,fill=GHI))+
    geom_tile(color= "white",size=0.1) + 
    scale_fill_viridis(name="GHI",option ="C") +
    facet_grid( year~month)+
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", breaks = unique(heatmap$hour))+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks =c(1,10,20,31))+
 theme_minimal(base_size = 8)+
  labs(title= "Hourly GHI values", x="Day", y="Hour Commencing")+
  theme(legend.position = "bottom")+
    theme(plot.title=element_text(size = 14))+
    theme(axis.text.y=element_text(size=6)) +
    theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour="white"))+
    theme(plot.title=element_text(hjust=0))+
    theme(axis.ticks=element_blank())+
    theme(axis.text=element_text(size=7))+
    theme(legend.title=element_text(size=8))+
    theme(legend.text=element_text(size=6))
    theme(panel.grid=element_blank())
```

This code has been working fine previously. I am trying to make exactly same plot [as in this example](https://r-graph-gallery.com/283-the-hourly-heatmap.html) but for 1 year data only.

Please help.

TIA!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is only one issue in your code: While you created a new month variable based on the day number (which IMHO is unnecessary as your data already has a month variable) you did not convert the day numbers to the month day. Fixing that should or will give you your desired result:

```
library(tidyverse)

data <- read_csv("data.csv")

heatmap <- data |> 
  select(GHI, month, day = Day, time = Time) |> 
  mutate(hour = hour(time), month = factor(month, month.abb), year = 2023) |> 
  mutate(day1 = day(as.Date(paste(year, day), "%Y %j")))

ggplot(heatmap, aes(day1, hour, fill = GHI)) +
  geom_tile(color = "white", size = 0.1) +
  scale_fill_viridis_c(name = "GHI", option = "C") +
  facet_grid(year ~ month) +
  scale_y_continuous(trans = "reverse", breaks = unique(heatmap$hour)) +
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = c(1, 10, 20, 31)) +
  theme_minimal(base_size = 8) +
  labs(title = "Hourly GHI values", x = "Day", y = "Hour Commencing") +
  theme(legend.position = "bottom") +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(size = 14)) +
  theme(axis.text.y = element_text(size = 6)) +
  theme(strip.background = element_rect(colour = "white")) +
  theme(plot.title = element_text(hjust = 0)) +
  theme(axis.ticks = element_blank()) +
  theme(axis.text = element_text(size = 7)) +
  theme(legend.title = element_text(size = 8)) +
  theme(legend.text = element_text(size = 6)) +
  theme(panel.grid = element_blank())
```

[image]